# How do I access submitted form values in my NodeJS POST endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, postman

Feels like it should be super easy but I'm stumped. How does my endpoint get ahold of the form data submitted to it? All I'm getting is a blank. I'm using Postman to send a POST request to my endpoint (I have several other endpoints that work but GET requests).

In the code below I try to have the server echo back one of the form values I transmit using POSTMAN.

```
import express from "express";

app.post('/api/projects/', async (req, res) => {

  const label = req.body.label;

  res.send(label).status(201);
});
```

I tried to send a POST request using POSTMAN directly to my endpoint expecting "TEST" to echo back. Instead I got nothing.

Comment: EDIT: found the answer. req.query was needed instead of req.body...

Answer (score 0):

The post request on the backend will receive data from the client side, when the client side request is sent with appropriate options, such as method, body, and header.

You are using Postman,

Set the Content-Type option in header section as JSON/Application, and in the body section,

Include your data like,

```
{
    label: "Your data"
}
```